# pre-commit fails to install isort 5.11.4 with error "RuntimeError: The Poetry configuration is invalid"

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, isort

[pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) suddenly started to fail installing the [isort](https://github.com/pycqa/isort) hook in our builds today with the following error

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pycqa/isort.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/builds/.../.cache/pre-commit/repo0_h0f938/py_env-python3.8/bin/python', '-mpip', 'install', '.')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
[...]
stderr:
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
[...]
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_3j1398p/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/api.py", line 40, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          poetry = Factory().create_poetry(Path(".").resolve(), with_groups=False)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-_3j1398p/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/core/factory.py", line 57, in create_poetry
          raise RuntimeError("The Poetry configuration is invalid:\n" + message)
      RuntimeError: The Poetry configuration is invalid:
        - [extras.pipfile_deprecated_finder.2] 'pip-shims<=0.3.4' does not match '^[a-zA-Z-_.0-9]+$'
```

It seems to be related with poetry configuration..

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Upgrading the hook to the freshly released isort 5.12.0 seems to be fixing the issue.

Looking at the commit stack from isort repo, it sounds like recent version of Poetry had a breaking change incompatible with isort <= 5.11.4 ([commit](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/commit/0d219a6e0b49b7f84ef0702b2387d5e14299bb8e))

Comment: Is it possible to freeze Poetry version in pre-commit?

Comment: @bagerard"apparently no" but I show you exactly how? please don't put words in my mouth

Comment: sorry, I was just trying to help but I indeed read the github issue too quickly. Anyway, I deleted the comment to avoid confusion. Re-linking the Github issue regarding freezing poetry in pre-commit here as it still good to mention it--> github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/2730#issue-1561600633

Comment: Upgrading to isort 5.12.0 did fix the issue a few days ago, but suddenly it appeared again yesterday. I'm using Python 3.10.9

Comment: strange, it didn't reappear in our case

Comment: Thank you, I was hitting my head on a wall all afternoon because of this error and your answer fixed it.

Answer (score 42):

Running `pre-commit autoupdate` was sufficient to fix it on my machine.

This will update `isort` version in `.pre-commit-config.yaml` to 5.12.0+, as well as all the other pre-commit utilities.

Comment: I didn't know you could do this! Thank you for writing this answer.

Answer (score 23):

Additional note: For people who must use `python3.7` (the support was dropped in isort `5.12.0`), isort released the hotfix `5.11.5`.

https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/releases/tag/5.11.5

> 5.11.5 January 30 2023 [hotfix]
>
> Fixed incompatiblity with latest poetry version

Related isort issue: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/issues/2083#issuecomment-1408300628

Comment: Could this answer be merged with @bagerard's answer?

Answer (score 11):

For me the solution was:

```
pre-commit autoupdate
```

Comment: This documented one should be the answer. It's a root cause solution. Good one!

Answer (score 7):

Adding to this post because it took a few more things to get my system working...

### Project fix

`.pre-commit-config.yaml` based on [docs](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/pre-commit.html)

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
  rev: 5.12.0
  hooks:
  - id: isort
    args: ['--order-by-type', '--length-sort', "--profile", "black", "--filter-files"]
    name: isort (python)
  - id: isort
    name: isort (cython)
    types: [cython]
  - id: isort
    name: isort (pyi)
    types: [pyi]
```

pin specific poetry-core version ([isort issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/issues/2077#issuecomment-1407378823) & [hot fix](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/pull/2078))

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.3.2"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

### System fix

uninstall/reinstall poetry [using official installer](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation)

`uninstall`

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_UNINSTALL=1 python3 -
```

> check .zshrc and remove other instances of poetry via `cat ~/.zshrc | grep poetry`

`install`

```bash
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
echo "export PATH=\"/Users/$USER/.local/bin:\$PATH\"" >> "$HOME/.zshrc"
```